# How to configure VPN settings?

Tags: 12.04, vpn

When I started working for my current employer, everyone (myself and my boss included) were on Windows 7 machines. About 6 months ago, my boss gutted Windows 7 on his machine and replaced it with Linux Mint.

I recently asked if I could do the same, but with Ubuntu instead, and he allowed me. So this past weekend I replaced my OS with a fresh new Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop installation, and am loving it so far.

I'd like to configure VPN so that I can work from home. My boss sent me the following instructions in an email, but it looks like they apply only to Linux Mint users:

```
Create a file in /etc/vpnc/ named ‘ourCompany.conf’, and put in there:
IPSec gateway 1.2.3.4
IPSec ID EmployeeVPN
IPSec secret 3dud934id94j49fj9j4f
Xauth username ourDomain\myUsername
Xauth password myPassword
```

**Edit:** Obviously, had to provide dummy values for all of these!

Below is a screenshot of the VPN configurator that ships with Ubuntu. Is this what I should be using, or is there another VPN client I should use? If this is what I should be using, how do my boss's instructions translate to this client? For instance, I don't see `IPSec` or `Xauth` settings anywhere in this tool. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you give link how your boss configured `VPN` for Mint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several VPN protocols available. You may need to choose a correct VPN for your need. For more info check this [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN)

In your case **Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc)** plugin is needed.

To install Cisco VPN open **terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc`

- open **VPN connections** from applet and click on "Configure VPN..."
- Choose "Cisco Compatible VPN(VPNC)" and click create
- Under VPN tab

  - Gateway: **1.2.3.4**
  - Group Name: **EmployeeVPN**
  - Group Password: **3dud934id94j49fj9j4f**
  - Username: **myUsername**
  - Domain: **ourDomain**

That it when you try to connect to this VPN, you will get a pop-up window asking for password. Enter the password to connect to the VPN.