# Installing a VPN

Tags: vpn

I use expattelly.com on my current PC and am worried that if I install Ubuntu that I will lose this VPN given to me to use it or not be able to re install it.  I live in the Cayman Islands and like to access BBCiplayer but can only do this with my VPN.  Can you assure me that I can still do this?

Answer (score 2):

The [expattelly website](http://expattelly.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=93&Itemid=204) says:

> "Yes!  We support PCs running any version of Windows as well as Macs and Linux"

But they don't provide a guide on how to do it. Generally, if they support Macs and Android, this means that the VPN technology they are using should be configurable on Linux, you just need a little bit of knowledge on how to configure it.

You'll need to use software on Ubuntu called **OpenVPN** or **vpnc** for example. Here are a few links on how to configure them:

- [How to configure VPN settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187284/how-to-configure-vpn-settings)
- [Ubuntu Help: VPNClient](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient)
- [Ubuntu Wiki: Introduction to VPN](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN)

What you can do is "Try Ubuntu" before actually installing it. You'll get that option when you try to install it from a USB/CD. When inside Ubuntu, try to configure the VPN connection. If it works, then you could safely install Ubuntu and do the same configuration again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as they say on their website, they also support Linux. To set it up, just open the network settings, add a new VPN connection and fill in the log in credentials.

But, have you ever thought about using a free VPN service rather than paying 60€s a year, for a simple VPN server hostet in the UK?
You could f.e. use [vpnbook](http://www.vpnbook.com/). They provide free VPN servers, one of them even in the UK. Just connect to that one and you can watch BBC iPlayer for free.